# can I use forEach to make every element of an array a new object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I created an array with many elements with a loop:

```
myArray = [c1, c2, c3...]
```

now I want to make each element into an object and assign different key values:

```
c1 = {image = path, value = number)
```

I tried to run `forEach()` but can't figure out the correct way to do so and I have not succeeded in finding the answer to it.

My guess was:

```
myArray.forEach(function() {
  let name = {
    image = path,
    value = number,
  }
  return name;
});
```

but there's no change in the elements in the log.

Any help or link to an answer that can help me here. First time coding here.

UPDATE: an easier solution was to .push all the keys and values of the objects when I created the array with the loop in the first place.

array.push({image: pathx, value: numberx})

Comment: That is what `map` is for!

Comment: how are the elements of `myArray` related to the new object? where comes `path` and `number` from?

Comment: the idea is that each key will have a function to declare it's own value. once I'm able to make each element into an object

Comment: ok, let me check on .map right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could theoretically push to a new array but this *is the exact usecase* for `Array#map`. `Array#map` maps old values *to new values*. The returned object from the callback is the new object and the returned array is the new array containing the new objects.

Semantically, `Array#forEach` is to plainly iterate over each element in an array, and possibly execute something with side-effects (which may include pushing to another array). But with `Array#map`, it's specifically used to transform old array values to new ones. Use the one that is specifically designed because it conveys a clear message to anyone else who reads your code.

```
const newArray = myArray.map(({ path, number }) => ({
  image: path,
  value: number
}));
```

Comment: I like the use of destructuring parameters. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm tempted to give them different names and use shorthand object properties.

Comment: **:-)** Tempting, but you're best off as you are, it just moves the renaming to the destructuring rather than the object construction. (I'm not telling you anything you don't already know.)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for any misleading with the way I presented the data. But now with this I actually did what I wanted... still need to do some more coding. But this helps me go forward. :)

Answer (score 2):

You *can*, but you'd be better off with a simple `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    let entry = myArray[i];
    myArray[i] = {image: entry.path, value: entry.number};
}
```

Or making a *new* array with `map`.

```
newArray = myArray.map(entry => ({image: entry.path, value: entry.number}));
```

Or if you prefer non-arrow functions:

```
newArray = myArray.map(function(entry) {
    return {image: entry.path, value:  entry.number};
});
```

Comment: @Rainman: I found it unclear in the question. Re-re-re-reading it, I *think* I know what they meant. I've updated.

Comment: I'm quite new at all these, so still not sure what I prefer, but thanks! now I actually did what I wanted... still need to do some more. But this helps me go forward. :) Sorry for any misleading with the way I presented the data. : )

Answer (score 0):

Array#map maps old values to new values. You may need to use the follwing instead of arrow functions as it is not supported in IE.
I just added dummy data in the object, you can change it.

```
myArray = ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
myArray = myArray.map(function(elem) {
    return {"image":"path"+elem,"value":"value"+elem};
});
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks @Alexander